# Attach sprite to Bullet - Box2D LibGDX kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, libgdx, box2d

I'm following some tutorials to be able to implement the parabolic motion. In debug everything works correctly, the parabolic motion responds correctly and the result works. Now I would like to insert a Sprite, and here my problems begin. In fact, the sprite perfectly performs the rotations of the object that is carrying out the parabolic motion but it absolutely does not follow the X and Y coordinates. thank you in advance:

Bullet function:

```
private fun createBullet() {
    val circleShape = CircleShape()
    circleShape.radius = 0.5f
    circleShape.position = Vector2(convertUnitsToMeters(firingPosition.x), convertUnitsToMeters(firingPosition.y))
    val bd = BodyDef()
    bd.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody
    bullet = world!!.createBody(bd)
    bullet!!.createFixture(circleShape, 1f)
    circleShape.dispose()
    val velX = abs(MAX_STRENGTH * -MathUtils.cos(angle) * (distance / 100f))
    val velY = abs(MAX_STRENGTH * -MathUtils.sin(angle) * (distance / 100f))
    bullet!!.setLinearVelocity(velX, velY)
}
```

How I'm trying to create sprite:

```
override fun render(delta: Float) {
    sprite.setPosition(bullet!!.position.x - sprite.width / 2,
            bullet!!.position.y - sprite.height / 2)
    sprite.rotation = Math.toDegrees(bullet!!.angle.toDouble()).toFloat()

    batch!!.use {
        it.draw(sprite, sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.originX,
                sprite.originY,
                sprite.width, sprite.height, sprite.scaleX, sprite.scaleY, sprite.rotation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incorrect way to use the Sprite class. There is an unfortunate design decision in libGDX that Sprite is a subclass of TextureRegion, which allows you you pass it to `SpriteBatch.draw()` as if it is a TextureRegion. When you do this, it ignores all of the settings on the Sprite.

If you use the Sprite class, you must use `Sprite.draw()` instead of `SpriteBatch.draw()`.

In my opinion, you should not use the Sprite class at all. You should write your own game object class that has the exact parameters you need and maybe keeps a reference to a TextureRegion. Then when you draw it using `SpriteBatch.draw`, you pass all the relevant data for position, rotation, etc. Then you are not having to keep redundant copies of your box2d body data in sync.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide me a general example?